# Rails 4 remove test generators (especially test_unit)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, generator

How I can remove test_unit generators to make them disappear from the `rails generate` list?

I have already tried some ways that **did not work for me**:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework nil
end
```

create app with `-T` option.

My `rails g` output:

```
[a lot of other generators skipped]

    TestUnit:
      test_unit:controller
      test_unit:helper
      test_unit:integration
      test_unit:mailer
      test_unit:model
      test_unit:plugin
      test_unit:scaffold
```

Comment: Could you post your generator output?

Comment: Updated. Nothing special just default test_unit generators.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your `config/application.rb` where you have the generations settings, you can hide some of the generators you don't want to see. For example:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.hidden_namespaces << :test_unit << :erb
  g.test_framework :mini_test
  g.template_engine :slim
  # ...
end
```

Comment: I had to do `g.hidden_namespaces << 'test_unit' << 'erb'`, but it worked like a charm!