# How do I customise test generators in default Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tdd, minitest

*Edit: Originally this was a Rails 5.2 question but it still seems relevant with Rails 6 and 6.1*

I am trying to customise which tests are generated by default in a vanilla Rails 5.2.x app. I don't seem to be able to configure the Minitest generators though. The following code in my `config/application.rb` causes a `error minitest [not found]` error when I try and generate a model.

```
config.generators do |generate|
  generate.test_framework :minitest, model: false
end
```

### My Assumptions/Understanding

- In Rails 5.2 the default test frameworks are [Minitest and Capybara](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html)
- Minitest gem is included automatically with `rails new`
- You can [customise generator behaviour](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#customizing-your-workflow) with a `config.generators do` block in `config/application.rb`
- `test_framework` ["defines which test framework to use. Defaults to false and will use Minitest by default"](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-generators)

Clearly there's a gap in my understanding or one of my assumptions is wrong.

### Steps to Reproduce

```
rails -v
    # Rails 5.2.1.1
rails new testing-test-frameworks
    # Bundle install outputs: 'Using minitest 5.11.3'
cd testing-test-frameworks
rails g model --help
    # Default [test framework]: test_unit [why???]

rails g model person
    # invoke    test_unit [why???]
    # create      test/models/person_test.rb
    # create      test/fixtures/people.yml
```

Strangely enough, the [official Rails testing guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html) also has lots of references to `invoke  test_unit` for both unit tests and system tests.

### Other Things I Tried

- I tried other settings in the `config.generators` block just to make sure it's working
- Given that the test_unit generators seem to be non-negotiable I tried changing the generations through test_unit; `config.generators.test_framework :test_unit, model: false`
- I tried to disable various other tests; `fixture:false, integration: false, model: false, spec: false, system: false, view: false`
- I tried to confirm I don't have any other gems or settings that might be messing with things (several [similar sounding problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12149734) related to an old version of FactoryBot/Girl)
- I tried variations such as `generate.test_framework :mini_test` mentioned in other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16872713)

### Questions

1. How do I control these generators?
2. Where (on the Internet or on my filesystem) do I go to learn about the valid options that can be passed to the generators for each test framework?
3. Why does the help system in my vanilla app say the default test generator is TestUnit when the [official documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-generators) says it's Minitest?

Comment: That doc is confusing. It says "Defaults to false and will use Minitest by default." Does that mean it has two defaults 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm attempting to partially answer some of my own questions (2+ years later) based on recent learnings (and based on Rails 6). If I'm wrong, hopefully Cunningham's Law holds true.

### 1. :test_unit == :minitest (more or less)

The first big point of confusion for me was that Minitest is indeed the default test framework under the hood but just about everything within Rails (still?) seems to refer to TestUnit/test_unit.

Examples include:

1. `rails g model --help` output (snippets below)

   ```
   -t, [--test-framework=NAME]                # Test framework to be invoked
                                              # Default: test_unit
                                                         ^^^^^^^^^

   TestUnit options:
   ^^^^^^^^
   ```
2. `rails g scaffold Example` output (snippets below):

   ```
     create    app/models/example.rb
     invoke    test_unit
               ^^^^^^^^^
     create      test/models/example_test.rb
     invoke  scaffold_controller
     create    app/controllers/examples_controller.rb
     invoke    test_unit
               ^^^^^^^^^
     create      test/controllers/examples_controller_test.rb
     create      app/helpers/examples_helper.rb
     invoke      test_unit
                 ^^^^^^^^^
   ```
3. The way we generate tests:

   ```
   bin/rails generate test_unit:model article title:string body:text
                      ^^^^^^^^^
   ```

### 2. Digging into Test Unit

Sure enough, if we look in [`all.rb`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5710128a84d5d03646dca6118db0e3a5715904ec/railties/lib/rails/all.rb#L17) we see that "Test Unit" is being included via the [`test_unit` Railtie](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/railties/lib/rails/test_unit). If (like me) you don't really know what a [Railtie](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Railtie.html) is, check out this [blog post](https://blog.capsens.eu/rails-6-boot-sequence-d289b44d2e94), I found it quite helpful.

In terms of what options we can provide in our `config/application.rb` `config.generators` block, I think the only options we can pass with `config.generators.test_framework :test_unit` are `fixture: true/false` (and maybe specifying a `fixture_replacement` path(?), based on the apparent defaults in the [test_unit railtie](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5710128a84d5d03646dca6118db0e3a5715904ec/railties/lib/rails/test_unit/railtie.rb#L12-L13)).

### 3. What else can "TestUnit" generate?

If you run `rails g` to get a list of available generators, only four TestUnit ones are mentioned in the output:

```
TestUnit:
  test_unit:channel
  test_unit:generator
  test_unit:mailbox
  test_unit:plugin
```

But the [Rails Testing Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html) mentions `test_unit:model` and `test_unit:scaffold` as well. And when I tried `rails g test_unit:foo` Rails suggested perhaps I meant `rails g test_unit:job` so that's three "undocumented" generators.

From what I can tell, those three extras come from [this generators folder](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/test_unit), along with a few others. If so, I think the complete list is:

- `test_unit:channel` *not in that folder, seems to be added by
  [ActionCable](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5cfd58bbfb8425ab1931c618d98b649bab059ce6/actioncable/lib/rails/generators/test_unit/channel_generator.rb)
- `test_unit:controller`
- `test_unit:generator`
- `test_unit:helper`
- `test_unit:integration`
- `test_unit:job`
- `test_unit:mailbox` *not in that folder, seems to be added by [ActionMailbox](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5cfd58bbfb8425ab1931c618d98b649bab059ce6/actionmailbox/lib/rails/generators/test_unit/mailbox_generator.rb)
- `test_unit:mailer`
- `test_unit:model`
- `test_unit:plugin`
- `test_unit:scaffold`
- `test_unit:system`